# Extract geographic subregion from grib2 file

Tags: grib-2

I'd like to extract a sub-region from a grib2 data file (GFS data from NOAA), writing the results into a separage grib2 file.  I'd prefer it if I could use a lat/lon bounding box (the GFS data is on a regular lat/lon grid) but can deal with converting the latitudes/longitudes to grid coordinates.

I've tried some things `wgrib2` but am running into configuration problems.  None of the [documented tricks](http://www.ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wd51we/wgrib2/tricks.wgrib2) directly address this.  Before I go further down that route, which will probably require compiling from source, I'd like to confirm that (a) `wgrib2` can actually do what I want and (b) fully understand the syntax for doing so. What looks like the relevant option for `wgrib2`, `-small_grib`, is marked as "beta", and it's not clear if "small grib" is just a term used in the help messages or if it is different from a "regular" grib file all together.

Alternately, if there are other tools/approaches for achieving the same ends, I'd like to know about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to download the regional subset of the GFS data from nomads.ncep.noaa.gov.  Just select the grib_filter and fill in the blanks.  The grib_filter web page has been using wgrib2 and the -small_grib option for 7 years, so the -small_grib option works.